# Waiting for a function to finish in node before displaying received data

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I'm trying to send back results data from my API call in Node. I have an HTML form with a search bar set up that takes the search term and fires off a search with that term.

Right now the data gets sent back and is empty on the first click, but when I click again, the data from the previous call is sent back to my HTML page, so I know there's something going on in regards to callbacks. I could use a setTimeout on the res.json() but that seems a little...juvenile.

I am pretty new to Node and I know the solution is rather simple...but I can't quite seem to figure it out.

Promises, callbacks, async. Maybe I'm just a little confused on where they go...

```
var result;
var Questrade = require("questrade");
var qt = new Questrade("env.KEY")
qt.account = "env.ACCOUNT";

qt.on("ready", function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});

function searchQt() {
  qt.search(searchTerm, function(err, symbols) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }

    result = symbols;
  });
}

app.get("/search", function(req, res) {
  searchTerm = req.query.symbol;

  searchQt();

  res.json(result);
});
```

I'm expecting to receive my data back on time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest and most incremental solution would be to move `res.json(result)` to the callback where the value of `result` is received.

```
function searchQt(res) {  // <-- note added argument
  qt.search(searchTerm, function(err, symbols) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    result = symbols;
    res.json(result);   // here it is!
  });
}

app.get("/search", function(req, res) {
  searchTerm = req.query.symbol;

  searchQt(res); <-- note added argument

  // res.json(result);  <-- commented out and moved above
});
```

You could also make things work with promises or async/await, but since you're already using callbacks, this is the most incremental way to get to working code.

While you're in there, you should remove `result` from the outer scope. You don't need or want that value preserved between requests. So just `res.json(symbols);` and get rid of the `results` variable entirely.

And passing `res` as an argument like that above is a bit of a code smell. Let's move the call to `qt.search()` directly into the callback for `app.get()` to clean things up a tiny bit. This eliminates the `searchQt()` function entirely:

```
app.get("/search", function(req, res) {
  searchTerm = req.query.symbol;

  qt.search(searchTerm, function(err, symbols) {
    if (err) {
      // handle error here somehow. maybe something like this?
      console.log(`An error occurred: ${err}`);
      res.status(500).end('An error occurred');
      return;
    }
    res.json(symbols);
  });
});
```

There are still some other improvements possible here. (I'm not sure if the `ready` event needs to fire before a search is tried, for example. So there might be a race condition there.) Promises or async/await might make this more readable. (People seem to like those better than deeply-nested callbacks. I personally don't mind the nesting, but I get it.) But that hopefully gets you going in the right direction. (And hopefully I didn't add any bugs that weren't there before!)

Comment: @MadWard Added material to eliminate the `res` passing thing. Additional feedback welcome.

Comment: Second snippet edited to include error handling + return, and to use `symbols` rather than `result`. Thanks for the comments.